# Upload CodeBuild artifacts *if* they exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a simple CodeBuild spec that defines artifacts to be uploaded after tests run:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - cypress/**/*.png
  discard-paths: yes
```

These artifacts are only generated if the test-action fails (a screenshot is captured of the failing test screen) and are being successfully uploaded to S3.

In the case that tests succeed, no `.png` files will be generated and the CodeBuild action fails:

```
[Container] 2018/09/21 20:06:34 Expanding cypress/**/*.png
[Container] 2018/09/21 20:06:34 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success: false
[Container] 2018/09/21 20:06:34 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

Is there a way to conditionally upload files if they exist in the [buildspec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html)?

Alternatively I could use the `s3 cli` -- in which case I would need a way to easily access the bucket name and artifact key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get around this, I'm creating a placeholder file that matches the glob pattern if build succeeds:

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - if [ -z "$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING" ]; then echo "Build failing, no need to create placeholder image"; else touch cypress/0.png; fi
artifacts:
  files:
    - cypress/**/*.png
  discard-paths: yes
```

Answer (score 4):

If any one still looking for solution base on tgk answer.
in my cas I wanna upload the artifact only in master ENV , so other than master I create a place holder and upload in a TMP folder.

```
 post_build:
    commands:
      #creating a fake file to workaround fail upload in non prod build
      - |
        if [ "$ENV" = "master" ]; then
         export FOLDERNAME=myapp-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).$((BUILD_NUMBER))
        else
         touch myapp/0.tmp;
         export FOLDERNAME="TMP"
        fi
artifacts:
  files:
    - myapp/build/outputs/apk/prod/release/*.apk
    - myapp/*.tmp
  discard-paths: yes
  name: $FOLDERNAME
```